# Book of Functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

I'm looking for a book/note or something else of functional analysis which has a lot of exercises and examples. In particular I need convergence (strong, weakly) in C^m spaces, L^p and also in sobolev spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Haim Brezis , Functional Analysis and Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations

Comment: Can you suggest another one? Thanks